# Removing words from list in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list 'abc' (strings)  and I am trying to remove some words present in list 'stop' from the list 'abc' and all the digits present in abc.

```
abc=[ 'issues in performance 421',
 'how are you doing',
 'hey my name is abc, 143 what is your name',
 'attention pleased',
 'compliance installed 234']
stop=['attention', 'installed']
```

I am using list comprehension to remove it but this below code is not able to remove that word.

```
new_word=[word for word in abc if word not in stop ]
```

Result:(attention word is still present.)

```
['issues in performance',
 'how are you doing',
 'hey my name is abc, what is your name',
 'attention pleased',
 'compliance installed']
```

Desired output:

```
 ['issues in performance',
     'how are you doing',
     'hey my name is abc, what is your name',
     'pleased',
     'compliance']
```

Thanks

Comment: In your code `word` is not a word, it's a sentence.

Comment: Do you want to just remove the word? Or do you want to remove the list element?

Comment: I want to remove just the word(stop) from the list of sentences.

Comment: problem with your solution is that you are looking for whole sentence in stop list,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, using simple regular expression with the `re.sub` method. **This solution removes numbers as well.**

```
import re

abc=[ 'issues in performance 421',
 'how are you doing',
 'hey my name is abc, 143 what is your name',
 'attention pleased',
 'compliance installed 234']
stop=['attention\s+', 'installed\s+', '[0-9]']

[(lambda x: re.sub(r'|'.join(stop), '', x))(x) for x in abc]


'Output':
['issues in performance ',
'how are you doing',
 'hey my name is abc,  what is your name',
 'pleased',
 'compliance ']
```

Comment: Sorry please, that was an error when I transferred the code from my editor to StackOverflow. Thanks for spotting it. I've updated the answer accordingly.
Cheers.

Comment: as a bonus you may add \s+ to substitute with \s to avoid double spaces

Comment: also if insists on 'words' you may add \bword\b to make sure you do not chop some peace of substring

Answer (score 10):

You need to split each phrase into words and re-join the words into phrases after filtering out those in `stop`.

```
[' '.join(w for w in p.split() if w not in stop) for p in abc]
```

This outputs:

```
['issues in performance', 'how are you doing', 'hey my name is abc, what is your name', 'pleased', 'compliance installed']
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just need to use `set` will good to this question. Because you maybe have more than one word at each item, so you can't use `in`. you should use `set` with `&` to get the public word. If it's exists public word with your `stop` set will return `True`. Because you only care about the rest part , so we can use `if not` here.

```
new_word=[word for word in abc if  not set(word.split(' ')) & set(stop)]
```

**UPDATE**

If you also want to delete all include digit item, you just simple do it with the following :

```
new_word=[word for word in abc if  not (set(word.split(' ')) & set(stop) or any([i.strip().isdigit() for i in word.split(' ')]))]
```

Comment: Thanks Frank!! I want to remove all the digits occurring in all the strings. Could you please help me with that too?

Comment: @user15051990 you just add ‘or any([i for i in word.split(“ “) if i.isdigit()]) at the end of if conditions. Because I have no computer beside me,so can’t do some testing if you got any errors let me know

Comment: @user15051990 I have already updated the answer, you can test it if it works as your expect.

Comment: But aren't sets unordered?

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = []
for word in abc:
    word1 = ''
    for remove_word in stop:
        word1 = remove_word
        word1 = word.replace(word1, '')
    list1.append(word1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it at least:

```
abc=[ 'issues in performance 421',
    'how are you doing',
    'hey my name is abc, 143 what is your name',
    'attention pleased',
    'compliance installed 234'
]
stop=['attention', 'installed']
for x, elem in enumerate(abc):
    abc[x] = " ".join(filter(lambda x: x not in stop and not x.isdigit(), elem.split()))
print(abc)
```

result:

```
['issues in performance',
    'how are you doing',
    'hey my name is abc, what is your name',
    'pleased',
    'compliance']
```

Hope it helps in any way :)