# Removing words from the list of sentences

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of channel names and I want to remove words from these names. 
I tried methods in this ([Removing words from list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51317357/removing-words-from-list-in-python)) discussion, but did not work for me.
I have these:

```
'Housekeeping.XTX_heater-0_Switch_Status'
 'Housekeeping.PDM_1__SW11_Status'
 'Housekeeping.Slim6_Imager-1_Switch_Status'
 'Power.BCM1_Battery_Cell_Temperature_degC'
 'Power.BCM2_Battery_Cell_Temperature_degC'
 'Power.BCR1__Battery_Discharge_Current_A'
 'Power.BCR0__Array_Temperature_degC'
 'Power.BCM0_Battery_Interface_Plate_Temp_degC'
 'Power.PDM_2__PDM_Current_A' 'Power.PDM_1__PDM_Temperature_degC'
 'Power.PDM_1__PDM_Current_A' 'Power.PDM_0__PDM_Temperature_degC'
 'Power.PDM_0__PDM_Current_A' 'Power.BCR2__BCR_Temperature_degC'
 'Power.BCR2__Battery_Discharge_Current_A'
 'Power.BCR2__Battery_Charge_Current_mA' 'Power.BCR2__Array_Voltage_V'
 'Power.BCR2__Array_Temperature_degC' 'Power.BCR2__Array_Current_mA'
 'Power.BCR1__BCR_Temperature_degC'
 'Power.BCR1__Battery_Charge_Current_mA' 'Power.BCR1__Array_Voltage_V'
 'Power.BCR1__Array_Temperature_degC' 'Power.BCR1__Array_Current_mA'
 'Power.BCR0__Overvoltage_Clamp_Current_A'
 'Power.BCR0__BCR_Temperature_degC' 'Power.BCR0__Battery_Voltage_V'
 'Power.BCR0__Battery_Charge_Current_mA' 'Power.BCR0__Array_Voltage_V'
 'Power.BCR0__Array_Current_mA' 'Thermal.WHL1_Measured_Current_mA'
 'Thermal.WHL0_Measured_Current_mA' 'Thermal.WHL1_IF_Temp_degC'
 'Thermal.WHL2_IF_Temp_degC'
 'Thermal.Prop_controller_-Y_panel__temperature_degC'
 'Thermal.WHL3_IF_Temp_degC' 'Thermal.WHL0_IF_Temp_degC'
 'Thermal.WHL3_Measured_Current_mA' 'Thermal.WHL2_Measured_Current_mA'
 'Thermal.SS1_Temperature_degC'
 'Thermal.Imager_flat_plate_EFF__temperature_degC'
 'Thermal.OBC_Temp_PPC750FL_degC' 'Thermal.OBC_Temp_PCB_degC'
 'Thermal.MTM-0_Temperature_degC' 'Thermal.AIM_Module_Temperature_degC'
 'Thermal.Sep_system_panel_-Z_+X__temperature_degC'
 'Thermal.OBDH_cardframe_-X_panel__temperature_degC'
 'Thermal.SS0_Temperature_degC' 'LIN.LIN_Failed_Nodes_Count'
 'LIN.LIN_BCM_Fail' 'LIN.LIN_Bus_Fail' 'LIN.LIN_Passive'
 'LIN.LIN_Master_1_State_Of_Health' 'LIN.LIN_Master_Up_Time'
 'LIN.LR_PA_Temperature_degC' 'LIN.My_IP_Packets' 'LIN.Switch_Error'
 'LIN.PA_Current_mA' 'LIN.S-Band_Power_Amplifier_ONOFF_State'
 'LIN.STRx0_Uplink_Reset_Count' 'LIN.STRx1_Uplink_Reset_Count'
 'LIN.Switch_Transaction_Fail_Count' 'LIN.Switch_Transaction_OK_Count'
 'LIN.TTC_0_Current_mA' 'LIN.TTC_1_Current_mA' 'LIN.TTC_Reset_Cause'
 'LIN.RSSI_dBm' 'LIN.TTC0_Temperature_degC' 'LIN.LIN_SPARE_STATUS'
 'LIN.LIN_Master_Reset' 'LIN.COUNT_FPGA_RX_STRx0' 'LIN.Lifetime_Cold_Boot'
 'LIN.Lifetime_Warm_Boot' 'LIN.LIN_Comms_Error_Count'
 'LIN.LIN_Node_Resets_Count' 'LIN.LIN_Bus_Reset'
 'LIN.LIN_Failed_Switches_Count' 'LIN.LIN_Master_0_State_Of_Health'
 'LIN.TTC1_Temperature_degC' 'LIN.UDP_Error_STRx0'
 'LIN.UDP_IPS_size_errors_STRx0' 'LIN.UDP_IPS_STRx0' 'LIN.UDP_Total_STRx0'
 'LIN.UDP_Valid_STRx0' 'LIN.UPD_IPS_errors_STRx0' 'LIN.Warm_Resets'
 'LIN.Cold_Resets' 'LIN.CAN_Reset_Count']
```

and want to remove these parts of sentences:

```
['Housekeeping.(including period)', 'Power.', 'Thermal.', 'LIN.']
```

expected output is:

```
'XTX_heater-0_Switch_Status'
 'PDM_1__SW11_Status'
 'Slim6_Imager-1_Switch_Status'
 'BCM1_Battery_Cell_Temperature_degC'
 'BCM2_Battery_Cell_Temperature_degC'
 'BCR1__Battery_Discharge_Current_A'
```

and so on.

Comment: post some code of what you have done and a proper input,output example.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In this example, we need to see your current code, what the list of channel names are, what you want to remove, your current results, and an example of your desired results. Until then, I am flagging this post for removal.

Comment: If you need something else/less/more (compared to what is present in the referred question), that has to be described.

Comment: @phalanx I was editing it:)

Comment: @JerryM. I was editing it:)

Comment: @tevemadar I was editing it:)

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved without regex, too:

```
new_list= [ w.partition('.')[2] for w in old_list ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following might work:

```
import copy
def remove_bad_words(in_stryngs, bad_words):
    bad_words = iter(bad_words)
    try:
        bad_word = next(bad_words)
    except StopIteration:
        return in_stryngs
    in_stryngs = iter(in_stryngs)
    out_strings = list()
    for stryng in in_stryngs:
        split_string = stryng.split(bad_word)
        blah = remove_bad_words(split_string, copy.copy(bad_words))
        out_strings.append("".join(blah))
    return out_strings
```

Here it is in-use:

```
bad_words = ["hello", "world"]

channel_names = [
    "Nationahellol Broadcahellosting Company (NBC)",
    "worldCworldBworldS (formerly world known asworld the Columbia world Broadcasting System)",
    "the Americaworldworldn Broadcashelloting Company (ABC)",
    "the Fox Broadchelloasting Coworldworldmpany (Fox)",
    "the ChelloW Televiworldsion Network.",
    "public broadcworldasting serhellovice (PBS)"
]

clean_chanel_names = remove_bad_words(channel_names, bad_words)

print("\n".join(clean_chanel_names))
```

The output is:

```
National Broadcasting Company (NBC)
CBS (formerly  known as the Columbia  Broadcasting System)
the American Broadcasting Company (ABC)
the Fox Broadcasting Company (Fox)
the CW Television Network.
public broadcasting service (PBS)
```

Answer (score -1):

lets say something like this:

```
import re
abc=['Housekeeping.XTX_heater-0_Switch_Status',
 'Housekeeping.PDM_1__SW11_Status',
 'Housekeeping.Slim6_Imager-1_Switch_Status',
 'Power.BCM1_Battery_Cell_Temperature_degC']
stop=['Housekeeping.', 'Power.', 'Thermal.', 'LIN.\s+']
print([(lambda x: re.sub(r'|'.join(stop), '', x))(x) for x in abc])
```

this is from the link you provided, I tested it and it works. give it a try

Comment: Could you explain what your answer does and why it works?

Comment: that last line is a regular expression in lambda, the logic is joining two lists to regular expression and replaces (sub: substitute) everything from the second one (here is stop) in first one(here is every x in abc) with ('') that means nothing or in your case delete it.

Comment: @phalanx oh i see my mistake thanx